# How do I get the contents of an uploaded file in a laravel rule?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to do some custom validation logic for uploaded files, so I created a `Rule` and started editing the `passes()` method. But the `$value` only contains the basename of the uploaded file.

How can I get either the file contents or the full path to the uploaded file so that I can validate the contents?

Here's the standard boilerplate Rule created using `artisan`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class MyFileValidation implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        // This is where I need the file contents
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The validation error message.';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so this is silly, but maybe someone else will have the same issue in the future and find this.

My problem was I forgot to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `<form>` element, so all that was actually sent to the server was the basename of the file. Which explains why that was all I saw in my rule.

After adding the proper enctype attribute I got an instance of `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` as the `$value` in the rule instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the `Reuqest` object through the global [`request()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-request) helper:

```
$file = request()->file('some_file');
```

You can also inject the `Request` object using IoC:

```
$request = app('Illuminate\Http\Request');
$file = $request->file('some_file');
```

Comment: `request()->file($value)` returns null in the `passes()` method.

Comment: @LarsNyström use the input element name instead of `$value`

Comment: That also returns `NULL` I'm afraid.

Comment: @LarsNyström please show unfolded results of `dd(request()->all());`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I just realized I forgot to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to my form... Now I feel stupid. After adding that the `$value` is actually an instance of `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`, from which I can get the absolute path.